# Show application on second screen even when logged off

Tags: windows-7, windows, display, user-accounts, external-display

I have second screen attached to my computer and I would like to use the screen to be showing something permanently. Actually I want just one special application to be running there in full screen. The application does not require any input from neigther keyboard nor mouse.

I know I can extend the screen and move any window there. But I would like to be also able to log off and let some other user (family member) to log to that computer withot affecting what is being displayed on second screen.

I don't know if this is a good way to go but this is what I tried:

I did go under C:\Windows\system32. I removed sethc.exe (after changing nececcary file permisions). I copied cmd.exe and set the name of the copy to be sethc.exe. Now anytime the shift is pressed 5 times command prompt appears insted of Ease of access window. From that command I am able to run any aplication even when I am logged off or when the computer is locked. I can use mouse to move new windows to second screen.

The problems with this approch is that the windows on second screen are hidden with desktop background when a user logs in. They reaper when the user locks the computer again and it disapers when swiching user.

So what is the right way to do what I want? How can I make the contents of second screen permanent?

Note that I don't mind security issues, risk of breaking the computer and I even don't mind writeng c++ code and calling Win API functions or anything what will be neccecary. The application I want to run there is open source ... so in case if it is realy neccecary I would be willing to look in to its source codes and try to modify it.

Comment: The application running on second screen is VirtualBox it filters USB with second keyboard and second mouse and it appears as if we have second computer where second family member can work. That is why we don't want user swiching on first computer affect second screen with virtual computer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is: You want to run two desktops/logins concurrently on the same physical machine.

This is referred to as **Multiseat desktop virtualization** and has been answered here:

[Dedicated mouse and keyboard for a virtual machine, is it possible?](https://superuser.com/questions/12284/dedicated-mouse-and-keyboard-for-a-virtual-machine-is-it-possible)